# Storage problems with cookies in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, cookies

I'm trying to store a new cookie for future visits but cookie is never stored and is not recovered in further calls.

```
<%
Cookie[] listCookies = request.getCookies();
boolean visitPrev = false;
for (int i=0; i<llistCookies.length && !visitPrev; i++){
    Cookie lc = listCookies[i];
    if (lc.getName().equals("cokkieRPL")){
        visitPrev = true;
        session.setAttribute("newVisit","false");
    }
}
if (!visitPrev){
    Cookie galleta = new Cookie("cokkieRPL", "access");
    galleta.setMaxAge(60*60*24*90);//90 days
            galleta.setPath("/RPL"); //I tried with galleta.setPath("/") too
    response.addCookie(galleta);
}
%>
```

Can anyone see the error? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What URL are you sending your requests to?

Comment: `requestURI: /RPL/pages/comun/BaseLayout.jsp
servletPath: /pages/comun/BaseLayout.jsp`

Debugging with Eclipse variable response/response/response/cookies is empty after response.addCookie(galleta);

Nobody know any solution? Is there anyone with experience in cookies?

Comment: Does that path match the path set in the cookie?